# How can I specify a file to be copied in an Android.mk file

Tags: android, java-native-interface, cygwin

Is there a macro or command to copy files? I'd like a 3rd party library (libThirdParty.so) to be copied to the output directory (lib). This is the contents of my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkFoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkFoo.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a build step I added for one of my .cpp files that's generated; you could do something similar.

Note that I was told that what I was doing was Not Supported by Google, so use at your own risk. I've been using something like the code below for more than a year, though. Here's a rough idea of what it would look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
# this was important for some cases; can't remember if it's important here, but I don't want to steer you wrong if it isn't
REAL_LOCAL_PATH:=$(LOCAL_PATH) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkFoo
# again, I'm being paranoid here
REAL_LOCAL_MODULE    := $(LOCAL_MODULE)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkFoo.c

$(REAL_LOCAL_PATH)/obj/local/armeabi/$(REAL_LOCAL_MODULE).so : $(REAL_LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi/libThirdParty.so

$(REAL_LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi/libThirdParty.so : $(PATH_TO_LIB_THIRD_PARTY)/libThirdParty.so
    cp $(PATH_TO_LIB_THIRD_PARTY)/libThirdParty.so $(REAL_LOCAL_PATH)/libs/armeabi/libThirdParty.so

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Note you'll need to define PATH_TO_LIB_THIRD_PARTY.

ALSO note that copy-and-paste may or may not work. Makefiles are notoriously picky about indents. I'd make sure that the "cp" line has a real tab indent, and that nothing else is indented. If "cp" doesn't work, then make may be delegating to CMD, and you can try "copy" instead.

Good luck.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. I also found this command: $(call add-prebuilt-files, EXECUTABLES, $("Include/libThirdParty.so"))

Comment: Basically this is just taking advantage of the fact that a `.mk` file is included into a makefile, and `make` runs it. These are just ordinary `make` dependencies. But when we tried this trick, it didn't work for us in our `Android.mk` files. I added an answer that documents what did work for us.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but found it while searching for something myself.

From the PowerVR SDK, Android.mk file.

You can create folders and copy files.

```
PVRSDKDIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)
ASSETDIR := $(PVRSDKDIR)/TrainingCourse/IntroducingPOD/OGLES2/Build/Android/assets

$(ASSETDIR):
-mkdir $(ASSETDIR)

$(ASSETDIR)/tex_base.pvr: $(ASSETDIR) $(PVRSDKDIR)/TrainingCourse/IntroducingPOD/OGLES2/tex_base.pvr
cp "$(PVRSDKDIR)/TrainingCourse/IntroducingPOD/OGLES2/tex_base.pvr" "$(ASSETDIR)/"
```

Comment: Basically this is just taking advantage of the fact that a `.mk` file is included into a makefile, and `make` runs it.  These are just ordinary `make` dependencies.  But when we tried this trick, it didn't work for us in our `Android.mk` files.  I added an answer that documents what did work for us.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a feature that is exactly intended for your use case: `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`

If you check the documentation in the `docs` directory included in the NDK, you will find `ANDROID-MK.html` which mentions this feature briefly, and `PREBUILTS.html` which completely documents the feature.  You can specify the source and destination directories, and you can specify a new name for the file when it is copied.

There is also `PREBUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY` which does the same thing for a static library.

It might be possible to trick it into copying arbitrary files... the above features are implemented by files called, respectively, `prebuilt-shared-library.mk` and `prebuilt-static-library.mk`.  Inside, they define an extension that must be on the file (respectively `.so` and `.a`).  You could probably make another .mk file that defined some other extension to enable copying some other kind of file.  But we have only needed to copy libraries and we haven't experimented with trying to trick the build system.

P.S. This blog posting is interesting.  It refers to `BUILD_PREBUILT`, which doesn't exist in my copy of the NDK.  I wonder if this blog posting refers to an earlier version of the NDK, which had `BUILD_PREBUILT` to copy any kind of file (with no check for a required extension).

http://karthiksden.blogspot.com/2011/03/copying-data-files-using-androidmk.html